# Mirror modifier using global axis instead of local

Tags: mirror

I'm very confused. The Blender documentation states :

The Mirror modifier mirrors a mesh along its local X, Y and/or Z axes, across the Object Origin.

Referring to the image, A is the result I would like to see, but B is what I'm getting. Both the origin and the local axes are in the right place but it still appears to be mirroring across the global axes.

I've also attached the Transform and Modifier settings for B.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here vertices are rotated but not the object. As the object is not rotated, its local coordinates and global coordinates are the same (concerning rotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lemon explains, the *Mirror* modifier use the object local axis, not the global. So to get what you want do not rotate your object in *Edit* mode, rotate in *Object* mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, the application of Rotation and scale in Object Mode via the shortcut:
*Ctrl + A* could be useful to you.
Not using it usually can create modifier problems. I also recommend that you check *'' clipping ''* in the modifier, which avoids mesh interpenetration.